# ORACLE Special JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle

Let me try to explain the scenario. I have two tables A (Columns - A1, A2, A3) & B (Columns - B1, B2, B3). I need to join table A with table B on A1.B2. For every join, table B has one or two records with different values for B3(X or Y). I wanna write one query where the JOIN query needs to pick the row with B3=X(if there's no other row with B3=Y); If two rows exists (B3=X & B3=Y), then the query needs to pick only the row with B3=Y (ignoring the row with B3=X).

Let me try to give some values to the tables & explain a little bit more.

```
Table A
********
A1   A2   A3
1    11   111
2    22   222
3    33   333
4    44   444

Table B
********
B1   B2   B3
6    1    X
7    1    Y
8    2    X
9    3    X
10   3    Y
11   4    X

Again.. JOIN is on A1.B2. The result should be as following,

JOIN Results
*************
A1   A2   A3   B1   B2   B3
1    11   111  7    1    Y
2    22   222  8    2    X
3    33   333  10   3    Y
4    44   444  11   4    X
```

Let me know if you guys have any clarification about my question.

Thanks in advance.
Yogi

Comment: Are X and Y the actual values? If not, are the values comparable?

Comment: Is B1 the primary key on table B

Comment: Table `B` has any other columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pick the rows from table B with the `ROW_NUMBER` function if you partition by the join column and order by your "picking order" column:

```
SELECT b1, b2, b3,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b2 ORDER BY b3 DESC) as rn
  FROM b;

1 Y 1
1 X 2
2 X 1
3 Y 1
3 X 2
4 X 1
```

Then you can filter the first row, the one with `rn=1`:

```
SELECT b1, b2, b3
  FROM (SELECT b1, b2, b3,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b2 ORDER BY b3 DESC) as rn
          FROM b)
 WHERE rn=1;

7  1 Y
8  2 X
10 3 Y
11 4 X
```

The filtered rows can then be joined to table a:

```
SELECT *
  FROM a 
  JOIN (
        SELECT b1, b2, b3
          FROM (SELECT b1, b2, b3,
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b2 ORDER BY b3 DESC) as rn
                  FROM b
                )
          WHERE rn=1
       ) bfilter  ON a.a1 = bfilter.b2;

1 11 111  7 1 Y
2 22 222  8 2 X
3 33 333 10 3 Y
4 44 444 11 4 X
```

If 'X' and 'Y' are not actual values, you can extend the `ORDER` clause with a `CASE` statement to allow for general values:

```
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b2 ORDER BY 
   CASE b3 WHEN 'Y' THEN 1
           WHEN 'X' THEN 2
           ...
    END ASC)
```

Edit:

```
 SELECT a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3
   FROM (
         SELECT a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3,
                ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a1 ORDER BY 
                   CASE WHEN a2=... AND b3=... THEN 1
                        WHEN a2=... AND b3=... THEN 2
                        ...
                   END ASC)
          FROM a JOIN b ON a.a1 = b.b2
        ) 
  WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Nice. Great Explanation. I just have one more sub-question. Is there a way i can put another condition Table A. With the same conditions, If table B has two records & one field(A3) in table A has a specific value(say 0), i wanna do the same (pick the record B with 'Y').

Comment: Sure, you only have to change the order, first join, then order. I'll edit the answer...

Comment: Let me rephrase it. Currently, If Table B has two records (with values X & Y for B3), we're picking one with Y. Now, i need to add one more condition where on the same condition (Table B has two records with X & Y), I need to pick the row with B3=X (instead of row with B3=Y) if A3=0. Please let me know if its a can-do thing. Thanks @Wolfgang

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. You've made my day a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use left outer joins as follows

```
select A.A1, A.A2, A.A3, 
nvl(BT1.B1, BT2.B1), 
nvl(BT1.B2, BT2.B2),
nvl(BT1.B3, BT2.B3) from A 
left outer join B BT1 on A.A1 = BT1.B2 and BT1.B3 = 'Y'
left outer join B BT2 on A.A1 = BT2.B2 and BT2.B3 = 'X'
```

A good explanation of the various joins is at http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is, how I would do it:

- Make the join
- group by B2
- take the max(B3)

That way you ensure that X is only picked, when there is no alphabetically higher value (Y) available

Comment: I need it without grouping. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

With UNION

```
select a.*,b.* from a,b
where a.a1=b.b2
and b.b3='Y'
union
select a.*,b.* from a,b
where a.a1=b.b2
and not exists (select bb.br from b bb where bb.b2=a.a1 and bb.b3='Y')
```

Without UNION

```
select a.*,b.* from a,b
where a.a1=b.b2
and (b.b3='Y'
or not exists (select bb.b3 from b bb where bb.b2=a.a1 and bb.b3='Y'))
```

The constraint here is that B has exactly 1 or 2 rows for each A's row